# Checking for button title overflows in Brightscript

Tags: roku, brightscript

In Roku's library, to add a button to a spring board screen, you use the method (see [doc](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifSpringboardScreen#ifSpringboardScreen-AddButtonbuttonIDasIntegertitleasStringasBoolean)):

```
AddButton(buttonID as Integer, title as String) as Boolean
```

If `title` overflows the button width, it will automatically truncate the text and append "...". But is it possible to programmatically check whether there was an overflow or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a nicely way to check that, but as workaround you have two options: check the string length for a maximum safe length or use GetOneLineWidth() method.

For the second option, you must know button's width, font family and fontsize, eg:

```
button_width = 450    'px

reg = CreateObject("roFontRegistry")    
arialFont = reg.GetFont("Arial", reg.GetDefaultFontSize(), false, false)
title_width = arialFont.GetOneLineWidth(titleString, 1280)    'maxWidth set to screen width

if title_width > button_width then
    'do your logic here
end if
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now the question is: in your example, you hardcoded the  button width. Is there any way to programmatically tell the width of buttons in the springboard screen?

Comment: There is no way to tell the width of the buttons programmatically as far as I am aware.

Comment: You can tell the width and position of any screen item via [ifSGNodeBoundingRect](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifsgnodeboundingrect.md)